# CSS: expand one row width over the page

Tags: html, css

I want a set of div be aligned in one single row going over the width of the page and scroll horizzontaly.

```
|----  page  ----|

[ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]
      <---->scroll
```

I have tried different options like floating left, inline displaying, etc but all my trials end up in something that goes in a second row with the width of the page:

```
|----  page  ----|

[ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]
[ ][ ]
```

here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eSkw2/)

css:

```
.container {
    width: auto;
}
.foo {
    background-color:red;
    width: 20px;
    height:20px;
    margin: 2px;
    float: left;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="foo"></div>
    <div class="foo"></div>
    <div class="foo"></div>
    <div class="foo"></div>
    <div class="foo"></div>
    <div class="foo"></div>
    <div class="foo"></div>
    <div class="foo"></div>
    <div class="foo"></div>
    <div class="foo"></div>
    <div class="foo"></div>
    <div class="foo"></div>
    <div class="foo"></div>
    <div class="foo"></div>
    <div class="foo"></div>
    <div class="foo"></div>
    <div class="foo"></div>
    <div class="foo"></div>
    <div class="foo"></div>
    <div class="foo"></div>
    <div class="foo"></div>
    <div class="foo"></div>
    <div class="foo"></div>
    <div class="foo"></div>
    <div class="foo"></div>
    <div class="foo"></div>
    <div class="foo"></div>
    <div class="foo"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do the job for you:

```
.container {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.foo {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color:red;
    width: 20px;
    height:20px;
    margin: 2px;
    zoom: 1; / for less than ie8 support
    *display: inline; / for less than ie8 support
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/PexbZ/1/

Comment: +1. But note that `inline-block` may not work as expected in IE<8. http://caniuse.com/inline-block

Comment: @showdev I don't think that web developers should support IE8 and older. Microsoft doesn't support WinXP anymore and Windows 7 has IE9 by default and supports IE11.

Comment: Fair enough -- that is a contentious debate. I just wanted to provide the info in case it is relevant to the OP's project.